# can we pass alias name in reference on join condition in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have following query but when i pass reference name of this alias column name it is showing invalid column name how can i do this

```
select OM.*,
       convert(int,Replace(Ltrim(Replace(left(OM.mstrefc,6), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')) as partycode,
       OI.*,
       Ac.AcctName,
       Ac.acctaddr,
       UN.UnitName
from ordemst OM
  join ordeitd OI
    on OM.mstCode = OI.ItdCode
  join Account Ac 
    on OM.partycode = Ac.acctcode
  left join unitdet UN
    on OI.ItdUnit = UN.unitcode and 
       OI.CompCode = UN.CompCode 
where OM.MstCode = 47 and 
      OM.MstType =79 and 
      OM.CompCode =117 and 
      AC.compcode =117 and 
      OI.Compcode=117
```

Comment: You can't use an alias from a select clause in a join clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an alias from a select clause in a join clause.

> column_alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause, but it cannot be used in a WHERE, GROUP BY, or HAVING clause

and apparently not in a join clause.

You have to replace the alias with the real thing:

```
join Account Ac 
on convert(int,Replace(Ltrim(Replace(left(OM.mstrefc,6), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')) = Ac.acctcode
```

[Taken from the MSSQL Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173451.aspx)